# numpy array creation & reshape command worked in 3.5.6, but not 3.7.3

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, type-conversion

I'm building a huge array to store the output of a simulation. This code worked fine & was programmed using 3.5.6.  Now, I'm converting it to deploy on 3.7.3, but one line of code is crashing the kernel.  Here's the code:

```
def frn(inds, format_array, r, p, q):
    #transpose the input dataset so regions are rows
simu_rand_transp = inds.T
    #reshape the numpy array to one long list of horizontal arrays
simu_rand_transp_flat = simu_rand_transp.reshape(1,(r*p*q))
    #create a list of regions & enumerate it
listr = []
for i in range(r):
    x = i + 1
    if i == 0:
        listr = [x] * (p * q)
    else:
        l = [x] * (p * q)
        listr = listr + l

    #split the region list into smaller sub lists & convert it to an array
listr = np.array_split(listr, r)
listr_arr = np.array(listr)
    #flatten the array
listr_arr_flat = listregions_arr.reshape(1,(r*p*q))
```

The second .reshape command crashes the kernel.  Originally, I thought it was a problem with the .reshape command.  But, as you can see, there is already a .reshape command earlier in the code string.  That first .reshape, however, is taking an actual array converted from a pandas data frame and reshaping it.  The second is trying to reshape an array of extended lists.

It seems to me that this is an issue of how the second array is created & not specifically tied to the reshape command.  I was hoping that someone out there might have run into a similar problem.

Comment: Error message? Traceback?

Comment: No error message.  It just stops & restarts the kernel.  That's the strange thing.

Comment: How big are the arrays? Could it be a matter of memory usage?

Comment: kernel - as in jupyter notebook?

Comment: Thank you both!  Yes, jupyter notebook.  The arrays are 36,740,000 rows x 5 columns. I checked with our tech people, the team responsible for supporting our jupyter lab installation.  They indicated that it can't be memory as we are alloted 4 gig.  Here's the strangest part, as this is part of a project: I did a freeze on the original jupyter lab installation (it was written elsewhere) & the 'client' recreated those dependencies.  Everything worked fine.  But it still won't run on the company jupyter lab.